# Change existing image size in the sheet

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a bunch of spreadsheets with images, some of then have different sizes.

I want to change the width of all images to it's own height.

**What i've already tried:**

```py
# For each spreadsheet in the folder...
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    for image in ws._images:
        image.width = image.height
```

But this code simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My first question would be are you looking to crop or just resize, not caring about original aspect ratio of the images?

You could use [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html).  Something like the below.

**Updated answer**

```
from PIL import Image
...

for i in range(1, sh.max_row+1):
     for j in range(1, sh.max_column+1):
          cell_obj = sh.cell(row=i, column=j)
          if image_loader.image_in(cell_obj.coordinate):
               image = image_loader.get(cell_obj.coordinate)
               w, h = image.size
               image = image.resize((h,h))
               image.save("image" + cell_obj.coordinate +".jpg")
```

Add more detail to your question if you need help parsing them from the Excel sheet.

Comment: I am getting the following error at the `img = Image.open(image)` line: `AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: Are you sure you are getting images from your spreadsheet?  What do you get when you `print(image)` ?

Comment: @gustavo you could also update your question with more details adding the code you have tried to pull the images from Excel etc and I could try to debug further